# Learn Python the hard way: Ex21, print output different than expected

Tags: python

```
def add(a,b):
    print "Adding %d and %d" %(a,b)
    return a+b
def subtract(a,b):
    print "Subtracting %d from %d" %(a,b)
    return a-b
def multiply(a,b):
    print "Multiplying %d and %d" %(a,b)
    return a*b
def divide(a,b):
    print "Divide %d and %d" %(a,b)
    return a/b

print "Let's do some math"

age = add(30,5)
height = subtract(78,4)
weight = multiply(90,2)
iq= divide(100,2)

print "Age: %d, Height : %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)

print "Here's a puzzle"
what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq,2))))
print "That becomes:", what, "Can you do it by hand?" #line25
```

Output:

Let's do some math

Adding 30 and 5

Subtracting 78 from 4

Multiplying 90 and 2

Divide 100 and 2

Age: 35, Height : 74, Weight: 180, IQ: 50

Here's a puzzle

Divide 50 and 2

Multiplying 180 and 25

Subtracting 74 from 4500

Adding 35 and -4426

That becomes: -4391 Can you do it by hand?

**My question**: I feel, looking at the print command in line25, output remains same till "Here's a puzzle". So, output should be:

Here's a puzzle

That becomes:

Divide 50 and 2

Multiplying 180 and 25

Subtracting 74 from 4500

Adding 35 and -4426

-4391 Can you do it by hand?

Because, clearly print "That becomes:" is coming before what. So, why is the final output different?
Thank you!

Comment: Why should the output omit the print statements?

Comment: the `add`, `subtract` etc. functions all have `print` statements which are executed as soon as they are called... The assignment of the `what` variable calls these functions before `That becomes`, so it makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `what` your functions use all have print statements in them. So these are executed each time the function is called. When you say `what = ...` you are calling the `add`, `subtract`, `multiply` and `divide` functions, and all of them print out a statement when executed.

To solve this, you should print "That Becomes" before defining `what`, and I think you will see what you expect to see.

Comment: Oh yes! Silly question :P Makes sense now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside each function, there is a print statement which prints the text as soon as it is executed.

So "what" variable holds the computed value and it will have all printable statements